# Leaflet map container is not found

Tags: angular, leaflet, maps

I"m trying to display a `Leaflet Map` in my angular component that is retreiving a Bank Agency Details.

I'm receiving this error :

> ERROR Error: Map container not found.

Here's my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from '../providers/rest.service';
import { SnotifyService } from '../../../node_modules/ng-snotify';
import { NgForm } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

declare let L;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modify-bank',
  templateUrl: './modify-bank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modify-bank.component.css']
})
export class ModifyBankComponent implements OnInit {
  bank:any;
  bank_id:string;
  latitude:Number;
  longitude:any;

  constructor(
    private restService :RestService,
    private snotifyService: SnotifyService,
    private router:Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { 
      this.activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe( params => {
        this.bank_id = params.bank_id;
        this.getBankByID(params.bank_id);
      })    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addMap()
  }

  getBankByID(bank_id:string){
    this.restService.getBankByID(bank_id).subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.bank = data.bank;
      console.log(this.bank);
    } , err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  addMap(){

    let map = L.map('map').setView([36.798854, 10.152786], 8);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    var Marker;
    map.on('click',(e) =>                                                                                                                                                         {
      let latlng = map.mouseEventToLatLng(e.originalEvent);

      console.log(latlng.lat + ', ' + latlng.lng);
      //remove previous markers
      if (Marker) {
        map.removeLayer(Marker);
      }
      // Add marker to map at click location; add popup window

      Marker = new L.marker(e.latlng, {
        draggable: true,
        icon: L.icon({
          iconSize: [ 25, 41 ],
          iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
          iconUrl: 'assets/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png',
          shadowUrl: 'assets/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png'
        }),
      }).addTo(map);
    });

  }




}
```

The html template contains a form to bind with the agency name and address, what I'm trying to achieve later on, is display a marker in the coordinates of the map. But I keep getting Map container not found.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook instead of the `OnInit` for running your `addMap()` method? My guess is that your DOM node hasn't been rendered yet.

Comment: No I haven't, how does it work? I'm still new to this

Comment: You can quickly just change `ngOnInit()` to `ngAfterViewInit()` and see if it works. Those methods are called by Angular for their respective lifecycle hooks. If it does work, you'll want to make sure your class implements that corresponding interface in your definition (not required but helps everyone to know which hooks are used).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by placing the `<div=map></div>` out of the `<form></form>`

Answer (score 1):

it's because your div container initialize after your js code.

you must put your js to footbar after div:

```
<div id="mapid"></div>

<script src="{% static 'map/js/map.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Worked  for me with Thymleaf